# html table loads before sql query is being excecuted

Tags: php, html, sql

I have an html table that shows results from sql query. 
The table refers to a `Basket` table in my DB and it simply shows the user's Basket in my website.
On the table I have *remove* button that once pressed, executing sql query that deletes an item from the user's Basket.
I'm using *post* method on html to do this :

**HTML**

```
<td><form name="myForm" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
   <input type="submit" class="css3button" value="הסר"  / > 
</td>
<input type="hidden" name="product" id="product"
    value="<?php echo $product; ?>" />
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){
    $removal = sprintf("DELETE FROM Basket WHERE
          Id='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']));
    $remove_result = mysql_query($removal);
 }
```

The sql query is being done and the item is removed ,the problem is that the page is being refreshed too soon (i suppose) and shows the same table again after i hit *remove* only after i refresh the page manually again, i see the right table without the item i just removed.
Do you think the problem is indeed with the page being reload before the query takes place? or is it another thing? is there any solution for that?

thanks!

Comment: Is the form posted with AJAX? If not, aren't you rendering the table on the server-side BEFORE executing the delete query based on the POST data? Be sure to select5 the data AFTER the delete query.

Comment: Would be nice if you also add the table code

Answer (score 0):

I think on your file the code to generate the table (or the sql query to select the items from the DB) is executed before this part,

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){
  $removal = sprintf("DELETE FROM Basket WHERE Id='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']));
    $remove_result = mysql_query($removal);
}
```

so the table is generated first and the deletion takes effect after that. As a result though the item is deleted from the database, the table still shows it until the next time you reload the page.

Simply place this portion of code before any other sql query of your script and the problem should be fixed.